# Hide "Log in to Community as User" Button from Layout Not Working

Tags: page-layout, customer-community, classic

In layout editing mode, the "Log in to Community as User" button can be removed from the template.  But doing so has no effect on the layout.  The button is still available for the users in the Contact detail page.

Has anyone experience same issue?

Our requirement is to keep "enable/view customer user" options but remove the "log in" option from our profile specific users.

We tried removing the "Manage Customer Users" permission but this removes all options and the welcome email is not triggered when the community users are created.

Any ideas on how to do this?

[image: Page layout edit mode]
[image: Contact detail page]

Comment: Can you try removing `Manage User` permission from the user's profile?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, the `Manage User` is not checked for the specific profile.